# Redo Undo drawing Canvas WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Doing some work on a Drawing Canvas and I'm wanting to implement a Redo and Undo button. I tried with a stack and an array, placing the last point drawn into the array then calling it back or deleting it but I cant seem to get it to work. Any documentation on this? Thanks in advance.

To comment bellow here is what I'm talking about

```
this.ContentPanelCanvas.Children.Add(line);
                oldPoint = currentPoint;
                Point[] redoTest = { oldPoint };
```

the above is what i tried to store the Oldpoint..

Later to recall that point and undo it I tried this:

```
private void Redo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ContentPanelCanvas.Children.Remove(redoTest);
        }
```

That gives me an error though. Whats wrong with it?

Comment: What didn't work in particular about your approach?

Comment: Well i have the oldPoint and currentPoint that was drawn on the canvas. I created a Point[] redo array in which I placed the "oldPoint" into the first index of the Array. But in my function called Redo I try to call that Point array back but I'm not sure how I would JUST delete that indexed point on the canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find the following sample meets your needs, it includes a method called undoLast, which will earse the last line drawn :-

http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/WP7-DrawingBoard-sample-Drawing--Ink--made-easy

Add the following line to a new undo button click event handler :-

```
myBoard.undoLast(SimzzDev.DrawingBoard.PenMode.pen);
```

Comment: not seeing that on this link.Its an erase function. I have that

Comment: okay thanks i see how that can work. But that means I have to change 90% of my code :/

Comment: I'm using a Canvas. Changing it to Inkpresenter disrupts all functionality